# How to read a file in python which has newline and tabs into a string?

Tags: python, json, fileparsing

I am trying to read a file which has tabs and newline etc and the data is JSON format.

When I read it using `file.read()`/`readlines()` etc, all the newlines and tabs are also read.

I have tried `rstrip()`, split etc but in vain, maybe I am missing some thing:

Here is essentially what I am doing:

```
 f = open('/path/to/file.txt')
 line = f.readlines()
 line.split('\n')
```

This is the data (including the raw tabs, hence the poor formatting):

```
        {
      "foo": [ {
       "id1" : "1",
   "blah": "blah blah",
       "id2" : "5885221122",
      "bar" : [
              {  
         "name" : "Joe JJ", 
          "info": [                 {
         "custid": "SSN",    
         "type" : "String",             }        ]
        }     ]     }     ]  }
```

I was wondering if we can ignore it elegantly.

Also hoping to use `json.dumps()`

Comment: If you simply have mal-formed data, I'm not sure that there is any truly reliable way to "clean" it. Trivially, if you replace all spaces, you'll nuke the content, too.

Some of the regex clues may help, but you'll have to know that you're trying your best to make good data out of bad data with poor accuracy.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use json.load() if the data is json?

```
import json
d = json.load(open('myfile.txt', 'r'))
```

Comment: Oh, I suppose json is choking?

Answer (score 2):

A little hack, inefficient I guess:

```
f = open("/path/to/file.txt")
lines = f.read().replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "").replace(" ", "")

print lines
```

Comment: There could be spaces inside strings.

Answer (score 0):

Where did that structure come from?  My condolences.  Anyway, as a start you might try this:

```
cleanedData = re.sub('[\n\t]', '', f.read())
```

That's a brute-force removal of newline and tab characters.  What it returns *might* be suitable for feeding into `json.loads`.  It'll depend greatly on whether or not the contents of the file are actually valid JSON once you clear out the extra white space and line breaks.

Comment: Might want to add `\r` to the list.

Comment: @agf - he certainly could, but it sounds like it's not valid even if you get rid of the extra whitespace, not to mention this isn't really a great answer if there's a chance that his values contain tabs or newlines.  It was just a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop over each line, you can just:

```
for line in open('path/to/file.txt'):
  # Remove whitespace from both ends of line
  line = line.strip()

  # Do whatever you want with line
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the usage of the json module?

```
import json

tmp = json.loads(open("/path/to/file.txt", "r"))

output = open("/path/to/file2.txt", "w")
output.write(json.dumps(tmp, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat foo.json | python -mjson.tool
Expecting property name: line 11 column 41
```

The comma in `"type" : "String",` is causing the JSON decoder to choke.  If it wasn't for that problem, you could use `json.load()` to load the file directly.

In other words, you have malformed JSON, meaning you'll need to perform a replacement operation before feeding it to `json.loads()`. Since you'll need to read the file into a string completely to do the replacement operation anyway, use `json.loads(jsonstr)` instead of `json.load(jsonfilep)`:

```
    >>> import json, re
    >>> jsonfilep = open('foo.json')
    >>> jsonstr = re.sub(r'''(["'0-9.]\s*),\s*}''', r'\1}', jsonfilep.read())
    >>> jsonobj = json.loads(jsonstr)
    >>> jsonstr = json.dumps(jsonobj)
    >>> print(jsonstr)
    {"foo": [{"blah": "blah blah", "id2": "5885221122", "bar": [{"info":
    [{"type": "String", "custid": "SSN"}], "name": "Joe JJ"}], "id1": "1"}]}
```

I only used the `re` module because it could happen for any value, number or string.